# (`[name="${name}"]`).value) -->what that part of the code says?

Tags: javascript

```
const [sobre, nome, titulo] = ['sobre', 'nome', 'titulo'].map(
    name => form.querySelector(`[name="${name}"]`).value);
```

```
(`[name="${name}"]`).value)
```

what that part of the code says ?

Comment: That part in itself does say nothing. The whole line defines an anonymous function that selects the first element of a form with one of those three names and returns *its* value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a string template. Basicaly, it's like concatenating string but directly in the string.

the selector output would be

```
[name="sobre"]
[name="nome"]
[name="titulo"]
```

Because we are replace `${name}` with the value of the `name` variable.

if you want a more concrete example, you could simple use the same loop, with a console log.

```js
const [sobre, nome, titulo] = ['sobre', 'nome', 'titulo'].map(
    name => console.log(`[name="${name}"]`));
```